# Is a language containing set of binary numbers which are divisible by number N Regular?

Tags: regular-languages

Let N be any positive integer, then is following language regular for every $N$?

$L$ = { $B_n : B_n(modN) == 0$ } where $B_n$ is binary representation of a number.

E.g, $L=\lbrace B_n : B_nmod31 == 0,B_n \ is \ a \ binary \ number \rbrace$ is regular? Will the language be regular for any positive number in place of $31$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce a finite automaton to recognize binary strings divisible by $N$ for any $N>0$. Use $N+1$ states, $s$ (the start state) and $q_i$, where being in state $q_i$ corresponds to having seen input $B$ which is congruent to $i\bmod N$.

The transitions are then easy enough: in state $q_i$ and seeing a $0$ input the machine would pass to state $q_k$, where $k\equiv 2i\bmod N$, since appending a zero to a binary string doubles the number represented. Similarly $\delta(q_i, 1)=q_k$, where $k\equiv 2i+1\bmod N$.

The start state is there solely to avoid the question of what number the empty string represents, and obviously $q_0$ is the final state.

Comment: How can we ensure the edges is transition graph made according to you won't result in accepting other languages?

Comment: @Tamas. Try it for $N=3$ to see what's going on. The only strings in the language are precisely those representing numbers divisible by 3, in this case

Comment: I have made for 3 or 4. Not sure it will work correctly for all or not.

Comment: @Tamas. Instead, it might help to ask "How could this not work?"

Comment: My brain applied pumping lemma to this question to think that this wouldn't always work. Because if a number is pumped randomly then obviously the string won't still be divisible by $N$